# Using squared residuals as a dependent variable in repeated measures ANOVA

Tags: repeated-measures, residuals, r-squared, model-comparison

I have two DVs (y1, y2) and two IVs (x1, x2) and 50 observations (states in the US).
I ran four correlations (y1=f(x1); y1=f(x2); y2=f(x1); y2=f(x2))

My theory is that y1 is better explained by x1 (as compared to x2) 
AND
that y2 is better explained by x2 (as compared to x1)

I know I can simply run two tests for differences in the coefficients (i.e., show that the correlation between x1 and y1 is greater than between x2 and y1; AND show that the correlation between x2 and y2 is greater than between x1 and y2).

BUT, I am looking for a test to examine the conjunction of events. Basically, I want to apply the logic of a 2X2 ANOVA, and examine the share of variance explained by different predictors--a sort of an ANOVA for model comparison.

I've tried using the following method, wanted to know whether it was ever used, whether it is faulty or not:

1. standardized all of my variables
2. ran the four correlations
3. saved the squared residuals for all four correlations (x1-y1;x1-y2;x2-y1;x2-y2)
4. entered the squared residuals as my DV in a repeated measures ANOVA with a 2(IV: x1,x2) by 2(DV: y1,y2) design and 50 observations.

My idea is that the distance from the regression line for each state is a state-level measure of how predictable it is based on specific IV, and that this distance should be subject to comparison across different IVs.

Does this work?